# Can't run code using the 'dotnet' run command in Visual Studio. "Couldn't find a project to run"

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have tried running this program a million times.  I am in the correct directory, `C:\Users\DylanT\Desktop\Project`, and the file is just named *Program.cs*.  When I use the `dotnet run` command, I get the error

> Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in C:\Users\DylanT\Desktop\Project, or pass the path to the project using --project.

I only have one folder named "Project" and the only file inside the folder is the program, so there shouldn't be any reason it shouldn't execute the program. How can I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The .NET Build System does not work with loose *.cs* files (or F# or VB.NET for that matter); it needs at least a **project**. You can generate a **project file** by using [`dotnet new <template>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new) as follows:

```
md MyProject
cd MyProject
dotnet new console
```

Now you have a folder `MyProject`, containing `MyProject.csproj` and a default `Program.cs` file.

To run it, you can now do

```
dotnet run
```

This will open and read the `.csproj` file, and it will use the settings and properties that are inside it to build all the source files into an executable, and then it will run that.

Comment: thank you @Peter B, i usually don't use VS Code, i use Visual Studio Express for the most part so this was very helpful.  I appreciate it!

Comment: I advise you to 'upgrade' to Visual Studio Community 2019. It is free for personal use, is more capable, and it supports all types of applications including .NET Core. See here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/express/

Answer (score 4):

As you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?tabs=netcore21) you have to call the command on a .csproj-file. You simply can not call it on a source code file.

Answer (score 1):

you should navigate to your project :

> cd project_name

then you can run your application using :

> dotnet run